# Zero Beta Portfolio in R

Tags: portfolio-optimization, beta

I am trying to solve the zero portfolio problem in R. 
Given n assets, the objective function is to minimize the variance of the portfolio
$$Min_x\;\; \frac{1}{2}x^T\Sigma x$$
subject to 
$$COV\left(x^T R, R^Tm \right) =0 $$
and
$$x^T \mathbb{1}=1$$
and
$$\mu^Tx \geq \tau$$
Where 
$x$ are portfolio weights, $\tau$ is a required return  and $R_m$ is a representative market index.

I have seen the relevant discussion [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16250/portfolio-optimization-zero-beta-portfolio) and the code provided but it does not fit the above specification.
Is it possible to solve that problem either with solve.QP or any other function?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I'm a little confused by your notation so this is a preliminary answer which I'll either delete or amend depending on your responses.

If $x^TR$ is a deterministic scalar how are you defining the covariance?

What I think you might be defining is the discrete case of covariance:

$$ Cov(x_iR_{m,i}, R_{m,j}) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i (x_iR_{m,i} - E[x_iR_{m,i}]) (R_{m,i} - E[R_{m,i}]) = 0$$

In which case I'm assuming that $R_{m,i}$ are fixed, known values, in which case this constraint probably reduces to an affine one.

Comment: In words. According to Morgan, I. G. (1975), the Zero Beta Portfolio is the minimum variance portfolio that is uncorrelated with a representative index $R_m$. The weights of the portfolio $x$ can be $>0$ or $<0$. There can be an other constrain that $B^Tx=0$ to ensure that portfolio is zero beta.

Comment: There was an article by Gordon Alexander that presented an algorithm for finding the ZBP, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304405X77900125 I started writing some code for this years ago but TBH I never finished the project. (In any case I think you should check your equations against a published paper, the ones you have here may be mis-specified as has already been pointed out).

Comment: The equations are from Morgan (1975) paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304405X75900100 subject to a latter comment by Ross who stated that $Rm$ (the proxy) must be in the efficient frontier, which is not always the case, if one use a pre-calculated index such as S&P500.

Answer (score 1):

The beta of your portfolio $\beta_P$ is given by
$$
\beta_P = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i \beta_i.
$$
This can be seen from bilinearity of the covariance:
$$
Cov(\sum_{i=1}^n w_i r_i, r_M) = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i Cov(r_i, r_M).
$$

Thus the constraint is linear and given above with the $\beta_i$ as constants and the weights are the variables that you want to optimize.

I assume that the solution will only be possible with a long/short portfolio. Thus, if your $\mu$ is a positive vector the condition on expected values that you have will render the problem infeasible.

Comment: The ZBP is unique. It's return is an interesting number, worth determining, but it is whatever it is. To require that it exceeds the threshold $\tau$ is either unnecessary or will make the problem infeasible.